# Salesforce Picklist If Formula

Tags: formula, picklist, record-type

I need some help. I need to create a formula to say

If field “Type” = Email, then field Nature_of_Meeting__c is not required. If “Type” Is any other value then Nature of Meeting is required.

Field : Type 
Data type : Picklist 
Field : Nature of Meeting 
Data type : Picklist
I would like the formula only to be applied to the following record type

Record Type :  Institutional
Record Id :  012R00000009EMq

I created the formula as

> ISPICKVAL(Type, "<>Email") 
>   && 
>   TEXT(Nature_of_Meeting__c ) =""

However its not working:(

Looking Forward to your help

Comment: I changed the formula to the following below, and it seems to work, how do i add a record type though

 TEXT(Type) <>"Email" 
&& 
TEXT(Nature_of_Meeting__c ) =""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

> AND($RecordType.Name = "UK: Institutional", NOT(ISPICKVAL(Type, "Action")), ISBLANK(TEXT(Nature_of_Meeting__c)))

What I've done:

- I've added the Record Type based on it's name to make sure it works even when Salesforce IDs change in Sandbox refreshes etc.
- Rather than using *ISPICKVAL(Type, "<>Email")* I used the *NOT()* function.
- Rather than using *TEXT(Nature_of_Meeting__c) = ""* I used the *ISBLANK()* function.

Update: Changed the validation rule according to comments below.

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation. i got the following error though  Error: Field Nature_of_Meeting__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Comment: Ah, didn't read well enough to see that Nature_of_Meeting__c was a picklist. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I had to change it to the following AND($RecordType.Name = "UK: Institutional", NOT(ISPICKVAL(Type, "Action")), 
ISBLANK(text(Nature_of_Meeting__c)))

Comment: Great, updated my answer. Please select it as correct by clicking on the grey check on the left of it for future reference. Glad I could help. :-)